# copy html code from "string" until the next "string"

Tags: python, html, parsing

I try to copy in a file part of a HTML code , I what to make it from a value until a next value , I try to do it with python .

here is my code :

```
import urllib2

html_code = urllib2.urlopen("web site")
html_code_list = html_code.readlines()

data = ""
for line in html_code_list:
    line = line.strip()

    if '<A NAME="table8">' in line :
      #copy the html contents in data
      #until find <!**********************************************>
      #break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import urllib2

html_code = urllib2.urlopen("web site")
html_code_list = html_code.readlines()
cpy = False
data = ""
for line in html_code_list:
    line = line.strip()

    if '<A NAME="table8">' in line:
        cpy = True
    if '<!**********************************************>' in line:
        cpy = False
    if cpy:
        data += line
```

Comment: smart , thank a lot